# how to get localfile using iframe tag

Tags: java, html, jsp

i'm trying to get the flash file which is in previous directory with iframe tag.But it's not working.Can anyone help me to solve this. Below is code

```
 <iframe src="../courses/slide1.swf " frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="myiframe" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's the error? A 404 file not found or something else? Have you tried to type in the absolute path in the browsers address bar? that will give you a good idea of what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your swf file into a html page and embedding that page in iframe.

Cheers

Comment: Too many people dealing with JSP fail to realize that to a browser, it is really just HTML.  If the developer can 'get it right in HTML', it becomes an easy matter to translate that into working JSP (ASP, PHP..).  As to the OP's "can u plz.." - can you please take the effort to spell all letters of words such as 'you' and 'please'?  This is not text messaging, we have the benefit of full keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be like this

```
|
|---jsp
|      |
|      |---yourJsp.jsp
|   
|--courses
         |
         |-----slide1.swf
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the iframe and use swfobject instead.